# Plugin for Eclipse Like image-debugger-plug-in-for-visual-studio.html

Tags: android, debugging, opencv, java-native-interface, imageview

Has anybody know about any plugins that I can use to view OpenCV images during debug? Just like the one found here at http://opencv.org/image-debugger-plug-in-for-visual-studio.html Or does anyone know if one can easily develop such a plugin for Eclipse (ADT)

Thanks

Comment: I too would be very interested in such an extension.  For Eclipse or for Qt creator.

Comment: Been looking around for a while, let me know if you find something!

Answer (score 0):

There is a support for this in Android Studio
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html